# Trying to webcrawl data using Python from the website using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, web-crawler

I am trying to import data from the URL(mentioned in the code). When I run the code, I do not get any information(like the plan name and rates) and gives me container div tags but not the contents. Also, I tried response.text but it gave me no results.I do not want to use Selenium. Is there a way to solve it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

from urllib.request import urlopen

URL="https://www.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plan?id=POW15475MBE3&postcode=2000"
response=urlopen(URL)
html_content=BeautifulSoup(response)
print(html_content)
```

or

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).text,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

I tried to extract the header using below

```
h1=html_content.find("div", {"class":"header-left"})
print(h1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website makes ajax call behind to load the data.

There are 2 xhr calls that are made to load the data. Probably you are looking at one of them.

```
import requests, json
res = requests.get("https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/POW15475MBE3")
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(res.json(), f)
```

The saves the json to the file.

Sample data in file:

```
[{"planData": {"planType": "M", "tariffType": "TOU", "contract": [{"pricingModel": "TOU", "benefitPeriod": "1 year", "coolingOffDays": 10, "solarFit": [{"type": "R", "description": "Powerdirect Retailer Feed-in Tariff (exc. GST if any)", "rate": 9.5}], "additionalFeeInformation": "Additional fees and charges may apply. Please see the Powerdirect fee schedules at powerdirect.com.au/fees", "fee": [{"description": "Fee may be charged when reconnecting or reading your meter when you move into a property or change retailer. Includes GST. Fees may vary.", "amount": 12.55, "feeType": "ConnF", "feeTerm": "F"}, {"description": "Fee may be charged when reconnecting in other circumstances, such as after disconnection for non-payment. Includes GST. Fees may vary.", "amount": 12.55, "feeType": "RecoF", "feeTerm": "F"}, {"description": "Fee may be charged when disconnecting or reading your meter when you move out of a property or change retailer. Includes GST. Fees may vary.", "amount": 12.55, "feeType": "DiscoFMO", "feeTerm": "F"}, {"description": 
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you.That was very helpful. Could you please guide me, how did you know that it is reading information from ("https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/POW15475MBE3")

Comment: open network tab in chrome developer tools. you will get all network calls made

Comment: @User_powerBI you can do it in that way also.

Comment: I read the url in the below format and the output is stored in JSON format in data . I checked the type of data and it is storing data as 'list'. response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     data = json.loads(response.read())  Now, I am trying to extract elements from data, such as fees and contract details. How can I read it from data object. Could you please help me. I tried with  print("tariffType", data[0]['planData']['contract']) but I am getting error.

Comment: @User_powerBI what all info do you need from the json?

Comment: I want to extract 'planData'(tariffType) and 'fee'(description, amount and percent) from this file. I am trying to extract using data object and print("planId",data[0]['planId'])
    print("postcode",data[0]['postcode']) gives me some result when I used trial and error, but when I try fee , I am getting error KeyError: 'contract'. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: It's a deeply nested json. You have to understand the structure of it

Comment: I will spend time to understand JSON structure. However, data is stored as list and len(data) gives me 1 as results and len(data[0]) gives me result as 13. When I tried to print the elements as     for i in data:
        print(data[0][i]), I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' error. What is wrong in here?